# Docusign API and printing documents

Tags: printing, docusignapi

I am able to create an e-signature with a pdf on the docusign api that I have setup within the Docusign sandbox. However, one of the requirements for my project is to pre-populate the pdf on docusign and then render it into a browser for printing.

Whenever I create the document within the envelope for e-signature, all of the passed-in fields are in the document. However, if I only create the document, then try to view it, all of the fields I am passing in are blank.

How can I have these passed in fields to stay persistent within the envelope document and then show that document within a browser?

Comment: can you share your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to say what you're doing wrong. 
I can tell you how it should be done. Not sure what lang you're using. in C# you can do this:

```
    // Add the tabs model (including the SignHere tab) to the signer.
    // The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    // Tabs are set per recipient/signer
    Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
    {
        SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere },
        TextTabs = new List<Text> { textLegal, textFamiliar, textSalary }
    };
    signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;
    Recipients recipients = new Recipients
    {
        Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 }
    };
```

(you can find the full code example and all the other languages in our [code example on the Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-envelope-tab-values))